# Validate Django Time

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am not able validate the date.
my goal is to raise an error if the date entered is less than today.

**forms.py**

```
class user(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        date = self.cleaned_data['date_one']
        if date < datetime.date.now()
            raise forms.ValidationError('No past Date')
        return date
    class Meta:
        model = user_model
        widgets = {
            'date_one': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
            }
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class user_model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    contact = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,null=True)
    date_one = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**This is the error**

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Can you post full trace back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code should go in `clean_date_one`, not `clean`.

```
def clean_date_one(self):
    date = self.cleaned_data['date_one']
    if date < datetime.date.now()
        raise forms.ValidationError('No past Date')
    return date
```

The reason you got that error is that `clean` is for validating the whole form, and needs to return a dictionary of all values rather than just one.